# Do we say someone has wrinkles "on" or "in" their forehead?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request, prepositional-phrases

I asked some native speakers, and they all say that "**she has wrinkles on her forehead**".

However, the dictionary says "**[He had deep wrinkles in his forehead.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrinkle_1?q=wrinkle)**" and "**[I tried to iron out the wrinkles in my shirt.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrinkle_1?q=wrinkle)**".

Another dictionary says "**[They were always paired with some sign of effort — eyes narrowing, drawing a wrinkle on his forehead.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrinkle)**"

I wonder why the first dictionary says "**wrinkles in his forehead.**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He has wrinkles on his forehead

The native speakers are referring to the surface of his skin. This is the common way of talking about wrinkles because the wrinkles are visible.

> He had deep wrinkles in his forehead.

As evident from the word "deep", the wrinkles are situated below the skin surface and may or may not be visible to the human eye.

Comment: ***She*** has wrinkles on ***his*** forehead? Huh, how'd she manage that? Is there a way I can put my wrinkles on someone else's forehead? ;)

Comment: @Benjamin Sure you can, if you're familiar with [frequency separation](https://fstoppers.com/post-production/ultimate-guide-frequency-separation-technique-8699). :) By the way, thanks.

Comment: If you dig a deep hole, it's visible from afar. How can a ***deep*** *wrinkle* be superficial or invisible to the human eye  as your answer appears to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the English dictionary you consulted was old, and hasn't been updated in a long time. For me, I would always use 'on' in the above examples.